# How to print next line after regex search using python

Tags: python, regex, loops

I have the below text:

```
subject = "Madam / Dear Sir, ', ' ', 'The terrorist destroyed the building at 23:45 with a remote 
            detonation device', ' ', 'so a new line character is appended to the string"
```

I have used the below regex code to search :

`[p for p in re.split('\,', str(subject)) if re.search('(M[a-z]+ / \w+ \w+r)', p)]`

getting output: Madam / Dear Sir

Expected output  : The terrorist destroyed the building at 23:45 with a remote
detonation device

Please note the expected output should always be after the regex expression is found.

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: You are splitting on a comma, and then get the part that matches the regex `M[a-z]+ / \w+ \w+r` which is `Madam / Dear Sir` What is the logic to get the match `The terrorist destroyed the building at 23:45 with a remote detonation device`

Comment: I have a large text of words.So with regex expression i am finding the expression(Madam / Dear Sir) and then once it searches want to print the very next line(The terrorist destroyed the building at 23:45 with a remote detonation device).This method i want to apply in other documents

Comment: So like this? https://ideone.com/lvSV0N

Comment: This works fine but i want it to fix it after the regex expression is found i.e. want to fix this keyword (Madam / Dear Sir) and then the very next word.Can you please help me on it

Comment: I would first split and get rid of the unknow amount of "empty" parts, and then loop to get the next part https://ideone.com/gaNnYF

Comment: Great...that helps a lot...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the split a bit more `\s*',\s*'\s*` to match all the parts that you don't want until the next part that you do want.

Then use a loop to first match your pattern `M[a-z]+ / \w+ \w+r`. The get the next item if there is an item present.

Example code

```
import re
subject = "Madam / Dear Sir, ', ' ', 'The terrorist destroyed the building at 23:45 with a remote detonation device', ' ', 'so a new line character is appended to the string"
filteredList = list(filter(None, re.split("\s*',\s*'\s*", subject)))
l = len(filteredList)
for i, s in enumerate(filteredList):
    if re.match(r"M[a-z]+ / \w+ \w+r", s) and i + 1 < l:
        print(filteredList[i + 1])
```

Output

```
The terrorist destroyed the building at 23:45 with a remote detonation device
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/gaNnYF)